# Why does this vue component not render

Tags: vue.js

I've banged my head against the wall for 3 hours now. This simplest of possible components doesn't render:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    app
    <container></container>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="container-template">
<div class="container">
    container
    {{this.foo}}
</div>
</script>

<script>
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {foo:"bar"},
    created: function(){
        console.log("app created")
    },
});

Vue.component('container', {
    template: '#container-template',
    data: function(){
        return {foo:"bar"}
    },
    created: function(){
        console.log("container created")
    },
});
</script>
```

Running the snippet errors with `Unknown custom element: <container>`. However putting the x-template into #app doesn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the container component when you create your "app" but the container component hasn't been registered yet. Just switch the statements around and it will work.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    app
    <container></container>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="container-template">
<div class="container">
    container
    {{this.foo}}
</div>
</script>

<script>
Vue.component('container', {
    template: '#container-template',
    data: function(){
        return {foo:"bar"}
    },
    created: function(){
        console.log("container created")
    },
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {foo:"bar"},
    created: function(){
        console.log("app created")
    },
});

</script>
```

Comment: if a bonus question is allowed: how could I get the vue debug output locally when running in web server? would be happy to open new question, too

Comment: not sure what you means for `vue debug output locally when running in web server`. Your Vue app is running in the browser (even SSR like Nuxt.js). so if you'd like to see the debug output, open the browser console/Vue Dev tools.